# How to Use IHTTPClientFactory in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build the most basic functionality to simply get and return the results from a webpage. I am reading the documentation on Microsoft's website on how to use IHttpClientFactory and I just simply do not understand how to use it. Here's my class:

```
public class TestHttpClient : PageModel
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public TestHttpClient(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public async Task Authenticate()
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.google.com/");

        HttpClient client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        System.IO.Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    }
}
```

I just don't get how to use this. Do I have to create a new instance of TestHttpClient every time I want to use that Authenticate method()? It just doesn't make any sense. I've been at it for hours. Also, how do I make this whole class static (including _clientFactory)? Creating instances of it seems incredibly strange.

Comment: what kind of project are you writing? if its .net core with asp.net - you should just create a strongly typed client.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation for IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1), if your goal is to simply get and return the results from a web page, might I suggest that it would be much simpler to use an [HttpClient object?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: I am doing a asp.net core application. I used "services.AddHttpClient();" in the  ConfigureServices method. I have used a HttpClient object in the past but I am trying to do things the right way even if its only light usage!

Comment: The easiest approach is to use [typed clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients).

Comment: Hey Stephen thanks I just managed to figure the typed clients method out. I have no idea what the other methods are all about but typed clients definitely seems the most logical way to do it. Cheers